# Which Netweaver version do I need for BASE CORRESPONDING?

Tags: abap

I have the following piece of code.

```
REPORT zzz.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA:
      lt_t100 TYPE t000_t,
      ls_t000_template TYPE t000.
    
    lt_t100 = VALUE #( BASE ( CORRESPONDING #( ls_t000_template ) ) cccategory = 'P' ).
    lt_t100 = VALUE #( BASE lt_t100
      ( VALUE #( BASE ( CORRESPONDING #( ls_t000_template ) ) cccategory = 'E' ) )
    ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

In the editor it looks like it should be compilable, because everything is highlighted in a right way.

[image: Coding in the editor]

Even though this does not compile. My assumption here is that I do not have high enough a version of the SAP Netweaver.

[image: Compilation errors]

Which version at least do I need to make this code compile?

Comment: VALUE+BASE+CORRESPONDING is (probably) 7.4, but I don't really get the error messages (METHOD "" is unknown PROTECTED or PRIVATE). ABAP-OO is about 20 years old. What is the ABAP version of the system you are working on?

Comment: The ABAP version in status dialog is `SAP_ABA 75D 0003 SAPK-75D03INSAPABA Cross-Application Component`. So not that old I think.

Comment: 7.5D is something like 2019 or 2020

Comment: Actually what you want to achieve with the code?

Comment: This is just a minimal working example. In the real example it should be an initialization of a table, that should act as a constant or rather as a template in the other parts of coding. I wanted to achieve that with least lines of code possible.

Comment: I rolled back your past edit, because it changed the question in a way which invalidated the answer which was already posted. Please don't do that! When you realize you asked the wrong question, please post a new question instead. And when you already know the answer, feel free to self-answer the question when you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CORRESPONDING` constructor operator [was introduced with Netweaver 7.40 SP05](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/abennews-740_sp05-expressions.htm).

The addition of `BASE` to the `VALUE` constructor operator for tables [was introduced with NetWeaver 7.40 SP08](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/abennews-740_sp08-expressions.htm#!ABAP_MODIFICATION_5@5@).

So when you patch your SAP_BASIS component to 7.40 Service Pack 08, then you should be able to use both keywords.

Comment: Strange, because my system is already SAP_ABA 75D SP03 and SAP_BASIS is of version 753 SP03.

Comment: @Jagger Then your problem might actually be that you are using those operators in the wrong way. But you didn't ask that in the question.

Comment: You are totally right! I was completely mislead. I will post the right syntax as a separate answer.

Comment: I also rephrased my question based on your comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Jagger You shouldn't rephrase a question to ask something different when it results in answers no longer matching the question. That's unfair to those who wrote answers and now need to delete them because they no longer make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1620671/philipp)'s comment I realised that I was doing it completely wrong.

Here is the right syntax that compiles flawlessly.

```
REPORT zzz.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA:
      lt_t100 TYPE t000_t,
      ls_t000_template TYPE t000.

    lt_t100 = VALUE #( ( VALUE #( BASE CORRESPONDING #( ls_t000_template ) cccategory = 'P' ) ) ).
    lt_t100 = VALUE #( BASE lt_t100
      ( VALUE #( BASE CORRESPONDING #( ls_t000_template ) cccategory = 'E' ) )
      ( VALUE #( BASE CORRESPONDING #( ls_t000_template ) cccategory = 'C' ) )
      ( VALUE #( BASE CORRESPONDING #( ls_t000_template ) cccategory = 'D' ) )
      ( VALUE #( BASE CORRESPONDING #( ls_t000_template ) cccategory = 'S' ) )
    ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```